# Alamofire response is nil

Tags: swift, error-handling, alamofire

I am facing an issue with Alamofire requests and interceptor.

I have two types of responses from my server -> Success response which is kind of object and the error response which is always a message what's wrong.
I founded a sample code to create a very own function for decoding two types of responses which seems to work well.

The problem occurs after the Alamofire adapt function is called (adapt add a cookies for each request) -> in my .responseTwoDecodable i'll get always response as nil but the status code is 200 and everything is fine, server returns object but alamofire is ignoring it.

Here is my code for each request:

```
func request<T: Decodable>(
    _ url: String,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(),
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil,
    interceptor: RequestInterceptor? = nil
) -> Future<T, ServerError> {
    return Future({ promise in
        AF.request(
            url,
            method: method,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: headers
            interceptor: interceptor ?? self
        )
        .validate(statusCode: [200, 201, 204, 401]
        .responseTwoDecodable(of: T.self) { response in
            switch response {
            case .success(let value):
                promise(.success(value))
            case .failure(let error):
                promise(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Here is adapt function:

```
func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, ServerError>) -> Void) {

        let request = urlRequest
        if let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.accessToken), let refreshToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Constants.refreshToken) {
            let access = [
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: Constants.cookieDomain,
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: Constants.cookieAccessPath,
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: Constants.accessToken,
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: accessToken
               ]
            let refresh = [
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.domain: Constants.cookieDomain,
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.path: Constants.cookieRefreshPath,
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.name: Constants.refreshToken,
                HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value: refreshToken
               ]
            if let accessCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: access), let refreshCookie = HTTPCookie(properties: refresh) {
                AF.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(accessCookie)
                AF.session.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookie(refreshCookie)
                completion(.success(request))
            }
        }
        completion(.success(request))
    }
```

And here is my decoding code for two decodables:

```
struct ErrorMessage: Error, Decodable {
    let message: String
}

struct ServerError: Error {
    var message: String
    var code: ServerErrorCodes
    let args: [String]?
}

enum ServerErrorCodes: Int {
    case unauthorized = 401
    case forbidden = 403
    case internalServerError = 500
    case notFound = 404
    case conflict = 409
    case unknown
    case emptyResponse
    case unserialized
    case userInput
    case coreData
}

final class TwoDecodableResponseSerializer<T: Decodable>: ResponseSerializer {

lazy var decoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    return decoder
}()

private lazy var successSerializer = DecodableResponseSerializer<T>(decoder: decoder)
private lazy var errorSerializer = DecodableResponseSerializer<ErrorMessage>(decoder: decoder)

    public func serialize(request: URLRequest?, response: HTTPURLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) throws -> Result<T, ServerError> {

        guard error == nil else { return .failure(ServerError(message: "Unknown error", code: .unknown, args: [])) }

        guard let response = response else { return .failure(ServerError(message: "Empty response", code: .emptyResponse, args: [])) } // HERE I AM GETTING A NIL AS A RESPONSE, BUT SERVER RESPONDED WITH CORRECT BODY AND 200 AS STATUS CODE

        do {
            print(response.debugDescription)
            if response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 300 {
                let serverMessage = try errorSerializer.serialize(request: request, response: response, data: data, error: nil)
                let responseCode: ServerErrorCodes
            
                if let code = ServerErrorCodes(rawValue: response.statusCode) {
                    responseCode = code
                } else {
                    responseCode = .unknown
                } 
       
                let result = ServerError(message: serverMessage.message, code: responseCode, args: nil)
                return .failure(result)
            } else {
                let result = try successSerializer.serialize(request: request, response: response, data: data, error: nil)
                return .success(result)
            } 
        } catch(let err) {
            return .failure(ServerError(message: "Could not serialize body", code: .unserialized, args: [String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!, err.localizedDescription]))
        }
    }
}

extension DataRequest {
    @discardableResult func responseTwoDecodable<T: Decodable>(queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated), of t: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<T, ServerError>) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(queue: .main, responseSerializer: TwoDecodableResponseSerializer<T>()) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let result):
                completionHandler(result)
            case .failure(let error):
                completionHandler(.failure(ServerError(message: "Other error", code: .unknown, args: [error.localizedDescription])))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am a newbie in Alamofire, so if something can be done in better way, I will appreciate your help or sharing your thoughts! Has anybody idea why this can happen? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the `error` value to see if you've failed for some other reason? Also, can you try one of the built in response handlers, like `responseString` to see if it prints your expected response?

Comment: It seems like very strange issue... I was able to get the expected results with just restarting Xcode and without changing even one line of code. After deleting the Derived data I was getting the same error, but the responseString was full of good data, error and response was nil. I am still stuck on this, without any progress:
`ERROR: nil`
`REQUEST: Optional(https://admin.eu/backend_develop/api/user?)
`RESPONSE: nil`
`DATA: Optional(142 bytes)`
`RESPONSE AS STRING: success("{\"admin\": true, \"name\": \"Peter\", \"id\": 35, \"registered\": true, \"registered_on\": \"2021-07-17\"\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I completely wipe out the code implementing `.responseTwoDecodable` and write very own solution:

```
func createError(response: HTTPURLResponse?, error: AFError, data: Data?) -> ServerError {
    guard let serverResponse = response else {
        return .init(message: "Unknown error", code: .unknown, args: [error.localizedDescription])
    }
    
    guard let serverData = data else {
        return .init(message: "Empty response", code: .emptyResponse, args: [error.localizedDescription])
    }
    
    let responseCode: ServerErrorCodes
    
    if let code = ServerErrorCodes(rawValue: serverResponse.statusCode) {
        responseCode = code
    } else {
        responseCode = .unknown
    }
    
    do {
        let serverMessage = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorMessage.self, from: serverData)
        
        return .init(message: serverMessage.message, code: responseCode, args: [])
        
    } catch (let error) {
        return .init(message: "Body not serializable", code: .unserialized, args: [String(data: serverData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "", error.localizedDescription])
    }
}
```

And calling it like:

```
.responseDecodable(completionHandler: { (response: DataResponse<T, AFError>) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                promise(.success(value))
            case .failure(let error):
                promise(.failure(self.createError(response: response.response, error: error, data: response.data)))
            }
        })
```

With this code I was able to decode all the errors from the server as expected.